# How can i select all javascripts objects?

Tags: javascript, list, class, constructor

here is my class :

```
class Player {
  static list = new Map()
  constructor(id) {
    Player.list.set(id, this)
    this.id = id;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I loop every players ? Thanks for answer

Comment: Why are you using `Map` here? You're only setting one id per instance.

Comment: Did you try `for (const player of Player.list) {...}`? That seems like it should work based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a Map where you want to loop through, you can just use the following example:

```
Player.list.forEach(player => {
    players.update();
    players.getUpdatePack();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the Map values like this:

```
for(let player of Player.list.values()) {
  player.update();
  player.getUpdatePack();
}
```